# read the header and replace a column value with another one in Python

Tags: python, io

I am a new bie to Python and I am trying to read in a file with the below format

```
ORDER_NUMBER!Speed_Status!Days!
10!YES!100!
10!NO!100!
10!TRUE!100!
```

And the output to be written to the same file is

```
ORDER_NUMBER!STATUS!Days!
10!YES!100!
10!NO!100!
10!TRUE!100!
```

so far I tried

```
# a file named "repo", will be opened with the reading mode. 
file = open('repo.dat', 'r+') 
# This will print every line one by one in the file 
    for line in file: 
        if line.startswith('ORDER_NUMBER'):
            words = [w.replace('Speed_Status', 'STATUS') for w in line.partition('!')]
            file.write(words)
input()
```

But somehow its not working. what am I missing.

Comment: you have        if line.startswith('PART_NUMBER'): might want to change the PART_NUMBER to ORDER_NUMBER

Comment: Yeah..sorry....Changed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read file ⇒ replace content ⇒ write to file:

```
with open('repo.dat', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

data = data.replace('Speed_Status', 'STATUS')

with open('repo.dat', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Comment: this is probably what @Programmerzzz want, but I just wanted to point out that MAYBE, he only wanted to replace lines that start with "PART_NUMBER" or really "ORDER_NUMBER".

Answer (score 1):

The ideal way would be to use the `fileinput` module to replace the file contents in-place instead of opening the file in update mode `r+`

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input("repo.dat", inplace=True):
    if line.startswith('ORDER_NUMBER'):
        print (line.replace("Speed_Status", "STATUS"), end="")
    else:
        print (line, end="")
```

As for why your attempt didn't work, the logic to form the `words` is quite incorrect, when you partition the line based on `!`, the list you formed back is in out of order as `['ORDER_NUMBER', '!', 'STATUS!Days!\n']` with the embedded new-line. Also your `write()` call would never take a non-character buffer object. You need to have cast it into a string format to print it.